# .htaccess rewrite exception for letsencrypt doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, lets-encrypt

I have a custom application that needs to redirect all requests through a central router, and I need to add an exception for LetsEncrypt to make requests to the temporary `/.well-known` directory created directly beneath the document root.

Say my original `.htaccess` file is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^.*$ router.php
```

I modified it to read:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.well-known.*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ router.php
```

But I can see requests still being forced into the router.  Why doesn't this rewrite condition work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/\.well-known/?[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ router.php [L]
```

Using additional `RewriteCond` to skip files and directories and using `THE_REQUEST` instead of `REQUEST_URI`.

Comment: More or less, yes.  The problem was that I actually had a custom 404 interfering.